# How does canvas 2dContext.translate(...) actually work?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying create an app using `OnTouchListener` and `2dContext.translate`, with `2dContext = canvas.getContext('2d')`.
The listener will change pan values when the user touches the screen and canvas.translate new coordinates.

And now I solve a small problem, how does `2dContext.translate` actually work.
E.g.: I set first coord using `2dContext.translate(100,100)`, it is no pan, but real coord in a view. The second coord in the view are [400,400]. What is right, `2dContext.translate(400,400)` or `2dContext.translate(300,300)`?

I mean, do I have to set new coord to last coord like pan (100+300) or do I have to set second coord like fully new coord (400)? Do the coords have relative or absolute value in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Every translation is relative to the current origin. If you call `ctx.translate(x, y)`, your origin will shift `x` pixels in the `x` direction and `y` pixels in the `y` direction. Both positive and negative values are accepted.

If you need to maintain varying origin positions, use `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` to remember and reset previously-defined canvas attributes. These functions operate on a stack, so you can save multiple states.